# C++ установить точность вычислений для double

Tags: c++

имеется данный код, но он выводит не ожидаемый результат. как это исправить?

```
double s = 0.0;
for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
    s +=  1.00000 / i;
    cout << s << "\n";
    //printf("%.5d\n", s);
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А какой должен быть ожидаемый результат для суммы гармонического ряда?

Comment: сумма должна стремиться к 1

Comment: А как она может стремиться к 1, если уже *первый* член ряда - 1, а остальные больше нуля?

Comment: Результат будет единицей только если не прибавлять `++i` , а умножать `i*=2;`. Начиная с 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Приведённый код считает сумму [гармонического ряда](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4), а она является расходящейся, т.е. не стремится ни к какому пределу, а постоянно увеличивается.

Поэтому не стоит ожидать, что значение s сойдётся к 1 (это просто невозможно, т.к. сумма уже двух членов равна 1.5 и далее к ней добавляются положительные значения).

Comment: спасибо большое. я почему то думал, что гармонический ряд стремится к 1....